# Android app receiving INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY in emulator

Tags: android

I have a custom app, developed by a third party, which uses com.symbol.emdk as an additional library for barcode label printing to a Zebra device.
Using JetBrains Rider, I can compile, build, archive, and sign everything fine.  Deployed to an actual device, everything works fine.
If I try and run the app through the AVD emulated device, it fails to install because it's missing the library.

In the Manifest.xml file, I have:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.symbol.emdk" />
```

under the `application` header.

I have loaded the .jar file into my sdk optional folder ([~/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-29/optional]) and added it to the optional.json file.
I'm uncertain what step I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.